# string.length returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, undefined

```
function checkInputData() {
    $('.mainSearchSubmit').live('click', function () {
        var inputData = $(this).parent().children().eq(0).val();
        console.log(inputData.length);
        //this returns undefined
        console.log(inputData);
        //and this returns text from inpu so i know there is data
    });
 }
```

Any ideas why is this happening, in other cases when retrieving val() from input it always comes as string??

Comment: `inputData ` does have text in it in the first place ? Also `length` should return `0` or more not `undefined`

Comment: yes it returns data, only when apllyed .length it returns undefined

Comment: If you add in `console.log(typeof(inputData));` what do you get?

Comment: @Trolleymusic, it returns string.

Comment: But was that _after_ implementing the `String(inputData);` suggested below?

Comment: @Trolleymusic, no before, weird..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only explanation to `length` being undefined is if inputData is not a string. You neglected to mention what type of input you're working with, but in any case, casting to string should solve the issue:

```
function checkInputData() {
    $('.mainSearchSubmit').live('click', function () {
        var inputData = $(this).parent().children().eq(0).val();
        inputData = String(inputData); // Cast to string
        console.log(inputData.length);
        //this returns undefined
        console.log(inputData);
        //and this returns text from inpu so i know there is data
    });
 }
```

Comment: "" + $(this).parent().yadda().yadda() will also cast to a string